# Where can I find a list of Cake's table get $options?

Tags: php, cakephp

New user to CakePHP, and I'm struggling with the documentation.

I'm doing a simple table / model ->get() and see everywhere in the documenation the second parameter $options can be a multitude of things... but what are those?

Is there a master list of $options anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation for `get`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_get) says that it takes the same options as [`find`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_find). Specifics of what values can be provided for each option would be in the main manual.

Comment: That'll do it. Thank you.

Shame their documentation doesn't link $options to this very list. I searched for 30 minutes!